# Gridview is not displaying data with code-behind sqldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gridview and its binded with datasource which is created in the code behind file. And I needed to enable sorting and paging in the easiest way so I wrote as following -

In button's click event

```
SqlDataSource dataSource = new SqlDataSource(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString, searchQuery);
        dataSource.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
        dataSource.SelectCommand = searchQuery;
        if (txtSearchQuery.Text != "")
        {
            dataSource.SelectParameters.Add("searchQuery", txtSearchQuery.Text);
        }
        gridBookings.DataSourceID = dataSource.ID;
```

---

However, when the button was clicked, the gridview wasn't populated with data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to call DataBind on the grid:

```
gridBookings.DataBind();
```

Comment: Now its returning empty data. I'm sure the query is correct and there are data in the DB. 

However, if I change to -

`gridBookings.DataSource = dataSource;
gridBookings.DataBind();`

The grid is populated. However, I can't sort it.

Answer (score 0):

you must databind

```
...
gridBookings.DataSourceID = dataSource.ID;
gridBookings.DataBind();
```

Although I'd prefer this approach

```
...
gridBookings.DataSource = dataSource;
gridBookings.DataBind();
```

Comment: From what I've read on a blog, if I use DataSource instead of DataSourceID, I'd have to manually write the code for sorting and paging. Is it correct?

Comment: That depends on the control, but if you want control then yes. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786.aspx

Comment: So how would you recommend if I want it to get sorting and paging without minimal codes.

Comment: I'd say use the controls shipping with the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

difficult to say without seeing your full page markup and code behind.

In general after associating the DataSource you should also call:

```
gridBookings.DataBind();
```